# Visual Studio 2010 conversion of 2005 solutions (C++ projects) loses project dependencies

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

I am trying to convert one rather huge VS2005 solution with many C++ projects to VS2010. After automatic conversion I can see that some of the dependencies between the projects were lost and thus my VS2010 builds fail unless I manually re-add the dependencies.

Has anybody seen this behaviour?

Is there a fix for this?

Can I avoid having the dependencies dropped during the conversion by changing/fixing the VS2005 solutions/projects?

**EDIT:** And another conversion artefact is that like three header files in a single project are suddenly considered C++ source files (instead of just header files) and their compilation is attempted. The compilation subsequently fails because they do not include stdafx.h.

Comment: Did you check the conversion logs to get any clues about what has happened?

Comment: @nabulke: I have checked the update log. There are warnings but no errors. Most of the warnings are the MSB8012 warning, e.g., the TargetName and linker OutputFile disagree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS2010 project conversion is fraught. And if you haven't applied **VS2010 Service Pack 1** you will almost certainly be wasting your time.

Regarding project dependencies (you might not like this): MSBuild 4.0 (the VS2010 build agent) no longer looks in the solution file for project dependencies. Even if you managed to get your solution to build okay in the IDE, if you ever plan to build your solution from command-line build scripts, or a TFS build server, then **all your project inter-dependencies must be applied in each project**. Otherwise your projects will almost certainly build out of order, especially on multi-core machines where, by default, MSBuild 4.0 uses as many cores as it can find.

My team had to bite the bullet and manually recreate project dependencies in each project so the VS2010 solutions would build correctly in both Visual Studio and our TFS build servers.

Comment: dripfeed - does that mean that the project-dependencies defined in the 2005-solution will not automatically be applied to the 2010-projects ??

Comment: aha!: Quoting [The VS Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/12/21/incorrect-solution-build-ordering-when-using-msbuild-exe.aspx): *... If you're using C++ projects, you are less likely to have this problem, because in the upgrade process that converts .vcproj's to .vcxproj's, it moves any solution dependencies relating to them to project references for you. ...*

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and here's what I did: **first convert from 2005 to 2008 then from 2008 to 2010**. This helped me.